# Custom Post Type Category URL

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, url-rewriting, urls

I've created a simple CPT named `shop` which contains some shop items. After that I've added `category` support to it which works fine (`'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' )`). Then I created `template-shop.php` where I keep all my logic (I use `template` because I have multilingual support via `polylang`).

So lets say that currently my URL looks like: `www.foo.com/shop`

And now I want to "filter" my categories and I currently use the URL params to filter:

```
<?php 

  $current_url = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');

  // if param category exists filter by it

  if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $category = $_GET['category'];

    $args = array (
      'post_type' => array( 'shop' ),
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'category_name' => $category
    );

  } else {

    $args = array (
      'post_type' => array( 'shop' ),
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

  }

  $shop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

And it works fine

```
www.foo.com/shop/?category=bar
www.foo.com/shop/?category=baz
etc.
```

My question is - can I somehow "update" the logic so the URLs looks better? I'd wanted to for it to be:

```
www.foo.com/shop/category/bar
www.foo.com/shop/category/baz
etc.
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Enable the post type archives and use a post type archive template.

1. Enable the archives; e.g. when registering the post type using `register_post_type()`:

   ```php
   register_post_type( 'shop', [
       'has_archive' => 'shop', // the archives are accessible at example.com/shop
       // ...
   ] );
   ```
2. Then create a custom [archive template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types) just for that post type; i.e. `archive-shop.php`.
3. And you can use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) to rewrite `example.com/shop/category/<category slug>` to `example.com/?category_name=<category slug>&post_type=shop`:

   ```php
   // This should be called in `init`.
   add_rewrite_rule(
       '^shop/category/([^/]+)/?$',
       'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&post_type=shop',
       'top'
   );
   ```
4. You'd need to use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) hook to filter the main WordPress query (since I could see you're using some custom query vars/values). But in the archive template, you wouldn't need the custom `WP_Query` query (i.e. `$shop = new WP_Query`).

### Option 2: If you need to use a custom Page which displays posts in the custom post type.

And by "custom Page", I'm referring to a post having the type `page`. Also, the advantage of using this option is that you don't need to enable the default post type archives.

1. So firstly, get the ID of the page which is using the custom template (`template-shop.php`).
2. You'd use `add_rewrite_rule()` to rewrite `example.com/shop/category/<category slug>` to `example.com/?shop_cat=<category slug>&page_id=<page ID>` — **"shop_cat" can be changed** to other *non-reserved* name, but you'll also need to change the name in step #3 & #4 below:

   ```php
   // This should be called in `init`.
   add_rewrite_rule(
       '^shop/category/([^/]+)/?$',
       // Make sure to use the correct Page ID.
       'index.php?shop_cat=$matches[1]&page_id=2',
       'top'
   );
   ```
3. You'd use the [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) hook to add the `shop_cat` variable to the public WordPress query vars:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'query_vars', function ( $vars ) {
       $vars[] = 'shop_cat';
       return $vars;
   } );
   ```
4. In `template-shop.php` or wherever necessary, just call `get_query_var( 'shop_cat' )` to retrieve the category *slug* from the URL:

   ```php
   $args = array(
       'post_type'      => array( 'shop' ),
       'order'          => 'ASC',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
   );

   if ( $category = get_query_var( 'shop_cat' ) ) {
       $args['category_name'] = $category;
   }

   $shop = new WP_Query( $args );
   ```

Last but not least, there are other variations to both the above options, but the ones I provided should help you get started.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, will test it now. Just a question, will the rewrite work with polylang?

Comment: The rewrite rules in the answer *should* work, but only for the default language. How your Polylang URLs look - is it the default like `example.com/en/my-post`? Does the URL include `language` as in `example.com/language/en/my-post`? Do you want `/en/shop/category/foo` (note the `/en/` - language path) or that you want `/shop/category/foo` (no language path) to show posts in any languages?